# PHP/PDO multiple file upload then store filenames in array in mysql

Tags: php, multiple-file-upload

I almost have it but i need to store the filenames that are uploaded to one mysql field.
HTML form is standard

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label>Upload A File</label>
              <input class="form-control-file" type="file" name="fileUpload[]" multiple>
            </div>
```

php pdo code is here. As you can see I upload the file then pass the names to $this->fileName to be included in the main sql prepared stmt. **It works but only stores one of the filenames. I assumed it gets stored in an array, if so, how or is there a better way?**

```
  class addReminder extends dbconn {
    public function addNewReminder(){

           $this->exdate = $_POST['exdate'];
           $this->name = $_POST['name'];
           $this->category = $_POST['category'];
           $this->location = $_POST['location'];
           $this->notes = $_POST['notes'];



           try {

                     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                       $total = count($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name']);
                       for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
                         $fileName = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'][$i];
                         $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                         $newFileName = md5(uniqid());
                         $fileDest = 'filesUploaded/'.$newFileName.'.'.$ext;
                         $justFileName = $newFileName.'.'.$ext;
                         if($ext === 'pdf' || 'jpeg' || 'JPG'){
                             move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'][$i], $fileDest);
                             $this->fileName = $justFileName;
                         }else{
                           echo $fileName . ' Could not be uploaded. Pdfs and jpegs only please';
                         }
                       }

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO reminders (exdate, name, category, location, fileUpload, notes) VALUES (:exdate,:name,:category,:location,:fileName,:notes)";
                    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':exdate', $this->exdate);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':category', $this->category);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $this->location);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':fileName', $this->fileName);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':notes', $this->notes);
                    $stmt->execute();
                  }

           }catch(PDOException $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();
           }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `$this->fileName` on every iteration:

```
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
    ...
    $this->fileName = $justFileName;
}
```

And then your insert occurs after the loop closes, so you're only getting the last record. If your goal is to get a row per file, then you'll need to move the insert code inside the loop that so that it fires for each iteration.

Comment: No i intend on inserting  multiple files and store file names with one record insert of the "exdate","name", etc...

Comment: Basically I want to do one insert of a record i.e.  one:exdate,category,name,location,notes - upload multiple files and store the names of those files in what i assume to be an array and store that array in the one record under fileUpload

Answer (score -1):

Got it
with serialize()
https://makitweb.com/how-to-store-array-in-mysql-with-php/

```
  class addReminder extends dbconn {
    public function addNewReminder(){

           $this->exdate = $_POST['exdate'];
           $this->name = $_POST['name'];
           $this->category = $_POST['category'];
           $this->location = $_POST['location'];
           $this->notes = $_POST['notes'];



           try {

                     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                       $total = count($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name']);
                       for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
                         $fileName = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'][$i];
                         $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                         $newFileName = md5(uniqid());
                         $fileDest = 'filesUploaded/'.$newFileName.'.'.$ext;
                         $justFileName = $newFileName.'.'.$ext;
                         if($ext === 'pdf' || 'jpeg' || 'JPG'){
                             move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'][$i], $fileDest);
                             $this->fileName = array($justFileName);
                             $this->encodedFileNames = serialize($this->fileName);
                             var_dump($this->encodedFileNames);
                         }else{
                           echo $fileName . ' Could not be uploaded. Pdfs and jpegs only please';
                         }
                       }

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO reminders (exdate, name, category, location, fileUpload, notes) VALUES (:exdate,:name,:category,:location,:fileName,:notes)";
                    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':exdate', $this->exdate);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':category', $this->category);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $this->location);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':fileName', $this->encodedFileNames);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':notes', $this->notes);
                    $stmt->execute();
                  }

           }catch(PDOException $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();
           }
      }
    }
```